# Output Google search results to a file

Tags: google-search

Is it possible to output Google search results to a file.
Just the site names and links written to a file line by line.
Once could get the source file using curl and parse the HTML code but is there a Google service that does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SEOquake](http://www.seoquake.com) is an add-on for Firefox which seems to be doing that. It can  export Google search results in a CSV file which you can open with Excel. The export file contains:
[image]

- Each listing URL
- Any additional data you set SEOquake to retrieve

You can get the add-on [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3036).
Source: [SearchengineJournal.com](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/export-google-search-results-to-excel/11253/)